# Flexslider stop animating switching to another browser tab

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Flexslider stop animating and freeze when I switch to another browser tab or open some other software and come back to that page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("#flexslider-123").flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                controlNav: false,
                directionNav: true,
                itemWidth: 200,
                itemMargin: 0,
                minItems: 1,
                maxItems: 2,
                move:1

            });
        });
```

All other things are going good as expected.
Anyone can help please.

Answer (score 1):

With FlexSlider 2 you've got a new property *pauseInvisible*.
Add `pauseInvisible: false` and it will continue the slideshow after changing tabs.